# who decides the size of a byte, is it the Compiler or the CPU?

Tags: c++, c, byte

I know that a byte is the smallest addressable code unit of memory by the CPU, so byte size in x86-32 machine is 8bits, however the c++ standard states that `sizeof(char)==1 bytes>=8 bits`, so I can have a compiler for x86-32 machine that has `sizeof(char)==16 bits` which mean that byte is 16 bits.

So in this example byte is 8 bits regarding the CPU, and it's 16 bits from the compiler point of view.So **What is the definition of a byte, and what determine its size?**

Comment: a byte, in C, has `CHAR_BITS` bits (`CHAR_BITS` is defined in `<limits.h>`). The value is implementation dependent (same compiler with different options may have different values).

Comment: Even on a [Turing machine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turing_machine), `CHAR_BITS` must be at least 8 to be C compliant.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The compiler decides this. However, in the case of C and C++, the compiler typically follows the CPU for reasons of performance.

On a platform where the smallest addressable unit is 16 bits wide, a compiler *could* implement 8-bit `char` but it would have to (1) emit instructions to get the 8 bit units out of 16-bit "bytes" and (2) every `char*` or `void*` would need an additional bit to indicate lower/upper half.

Vice versa, you could implement a compiler with 16-bit `char` on an x86, but that would mean all C strings would take twice as much memory as they usually do and it would be hard to interface to the outside world, which speaks 8-bit `char`.

Comment: On the platform where the smallest addressable unit is 36 bits, bytes are actually 9 bits, and where the smallest addressable unit is 48 bits, the bytes are 8 bits.  (I'm not aware of a C++ compiler for the latter, but it does, or at least did have a C compiler.)

Comment: @JamesKanze But on such platforms, the C compiler will have to play a trick to make smaller units addressable, i.e. make `char*` out of a memory address + offset. (Also, IIRC the 36-bit PDP-10 had 6-bit character, not 9. But ISO C would not accept that.)

Comment: And... There's a reason why the standard doesn't require `char*` and `int*` to have the same size.  (In most cases, the hardware does have a limited set of instructions for reading and writing a single "byte", so the tricks are played in those instructions.  (See, for example http://pdp10.nocrew.org/docs/instruction-set/Byte.html, for a PDP-10.)

Comment: @larsmans if it's the compiler that decides the size of a byte, then doesn't this mean that in the hardware context there is no such a thing as a byte ?

Comment: @larsmans on `x86-32` machine, if I use a compiler that implement char as `10-bits`, how will char objects get allocated, are they going to require `16-bits` of memory(`10-bits` + `6-bits` of padding), or will it only occupy exactly `10-bits` in memory ?

Comment: @AlexDan Re: the first question, it depends on the hardware. Most machines are byte-addressable but not all of them (some embedded processors are word-addressable). Re: the second question, *I* would implement it to use padding because every other way of implementing that probably be maddeningly complex. But then I've never implemented, or even seen, such a compiler, and I don't expect I ever will.